# Verify if meeting datetime ranges overlap in an IEnumerable list of meetings

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime

I have an assignment where I need to find out if any of the meetings in a list of meeting class object have overlapping datetime ranges. What I have so far is this:

```
public class Meeting
{
    public DateTime Start { get; private set; }
    public DateTime End { get; private set; }

    public Meeting(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }
}

public static class StaffMeetings
{
    public static bool DoesNotOverlap(IEnumerable<Meeting> meetings)
    {
        DateTime start = new DateTime();
        DateTime end = new DateTime();
        foreach (Meeting meeting in meetings)
        {
            if (start != DateTime.MinValue && end != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                if (start < meeting.End && end > meeting.Start)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            start = meeting.Start;
            end = meeting.End;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var format = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat;

        Meeting[] meetings = new Meeting[]
        {
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 20:00", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 21:30", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 21:30", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:00", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:10", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:30", format))
        };

        Console.WriteLine(StaffMeetings.DoesNotOverlap(meetings));
    }
}
```

Using the provided data set, I get the correct result but as I add more meetings, my results start to fail and performance drops.

I feel that the problem is in how I am iterating the list. However, if I sort the list first, I can most likely improve reliability but my performance would probably drop. I feel that there should be an algorithm for this, but so far, I have not had any luck finding one.

Comment: Please provide data that fails.  If you sort you might be able to simplify the test.  And you should check that end > start for each meeting

Comment: I'd avoid calling methods DoesNotXYZ - it will lead to double negative confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without sorting this does not fail and it should
The second and last conflict

```
new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 21:30", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:00", format)),
new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:10", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:30", format)),
new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 20:00", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 21:30", format)),
new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 22:10", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 22:20", format)),
new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:20", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:50", format))
```

maybe something like this

```
public class Meeting
{
    public DateTime Start { get; private set; }
    public DateTime End { get; private set; }
    public Meeting(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }
}
public static class StaffMeetings
{
    public static bool DoesNotOverlap(IEnumerable<Meeting> meetings)
    {
        DateTime endPrior = DateTime.MinValue;
        foreach (Meeting meeting in meetings.OrderBy(x => x.Start))
        {
            if (meeting.Start > meeting.End)
                return false;
            if (meeting.Start < endPrior)
                return false;
            endPrior = meeting.End;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var format = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat;

        Meeting[] meetings = new Meeting[]
        {
            new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 21:30", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:00", format)),
            new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:10", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:30", format)),
            new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 20:00", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 21:30", format)),
            new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 22:10", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 22:20", format)),
            new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:20", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:50", format))
        };

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(StaffMeetings.DoesNotOverlap(meetings));
        Console.WriteLine(StaffMeetings.DoesNotOverlap(meetings));
    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Sorting first using OrderBy Linq operator solved the instability issue and change in the if statement within the foreach seems to have improved performance. Good job!

Comment: @DaveAdler See update for a little more speed

Comment: I think that you should merge those two if statements.

Comment: I posted an answer that reviews the issues with @t3chb0t 's code as well as the issue with input validation.

Answer (score 10):

Sorting is what actually makes it work but if you also want it to be more linq-ish and more solid then you should change the following things:

- move the overlap-logic into another method
- change the method to return an `IEnumerable<Meeting[]>` for meetings that overlap
- use `Any` to find out whether any meeting overlap
- make both methods extensions

Example:

```
public static IEnumerable<Meeting[]> Overlappings(this IEnumerable<Meeting> meetings)
{
    var last = (Meeting)null;
    foreach (var meeting in meetings.OrderBy(m => m.Start))
    {
        if (last != null && meeting.OverlapsWith(last))
        {
            yield return new [] { last, meeting };
        }
        last = meeting;
    }
}

public static bool OverlapsWith(this Meeting x, Meeting y) 
{
    return x.Start < y.Start ? x.End > y.Start : y.End > x.Start;
}
```

Gets overlapping meetings:

```
var overlappingMeetings = meetings.Overlappings();
```

or checks if there are any. It stops at the first overlapping pair found:

```
var meetingsOverlap = meetings.Overlappings().Any();
```

with these new extensions you are more flexible because you can easily check any two meetings overlap and it's easier to undestand than `DoesNotOverlap`. Usually it's better to write *positive* conditions and negate them if necessary rather than the other way around.

---

But even this could be further *improved* by overloading the two `<` and `>` operators:

```
public static bool operator <(Meeting x, Meeting y) 
{
    return x.End < y.Start;
}

public static bool operator >(Meeting x, Meeting y)
{
    return x.End > y.Start;
}
```

and making the `OverlapsWith` method still more *natural*:

```
public static bool OverlapsWith(this Meeting x, Meeting y) 
{
    return x.Start < y.Start ? x < y : y > x;
}
```

Comment: Did you test this.  That condition does not look right to me.

Comment: Now the order shouldn't matter.

Comment: if you don't order the meetings then you won't be comparing the meetings in the right order.  the first meeting in the array might overlap with the last meeting in the array but you won't check that meeting.  TL;DR you have to order the meetings.  then you have to take into consideration that meeting 2 & 3 overlap meeting 1 but meeting 3 doesn't overlap meeting 2.  I am working on a solution for it

Comment: @Malachi those are too many overlapping ideas at once, I give up ;-]

Comment: Check out my answer and my [tag:rags-to-riches] question --> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/144790/18427

Answer (score 5):

You are going to want to make sure that you don't have a meeting with a beginning DateTime more than the ending DateTime.  my suggestion would be to throw an exception when something tries to create a meeting with an end time before the start time.

so your `Meeting` now looks like this

```
public DateTime Start { get; private set; }
public DateTime End { get; private set; }

public Meeting(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    if (end < start)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot create a meeting that ends before it starts.");
    }
    this.Start = start;
    this.End = end;
}
```

I would have something built into the interface for inputting the meetings to make sure that the ***End*** does not come before the ***Start***,  so in other words I would have some validation on my input.

I like @t3chb0t's approach with the Linq, but some things were a little mixed up

with a little help from a good Code Reviewer I realized that the Static Boolean method `OverlapsWith` should be inside the `Meeting` class there is no need for extension here.

I also changed some of the variables to make the code easier to read, I changed the variable named `last` to `first` because it is really the first meeting and that cleared up a bug in @t3chb0t's code.  When I ran the code I saw that the 2 meetings were mixed up (first one was `y` and second one was `x`)  and it made the code not work

Here is my code dump from LINQPad

```
{
    var format = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat;
    Meeting[] meetings = new Meeting[]
    {
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 21:30", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:00", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:10", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:30", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 20:00", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 21:30", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 22:10", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 22:20", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:20", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:50", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:20", format), DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 00:00", format))
    };

    var overlappingMeetings = meetings.Overlappings();
    var meetingsOverlap = meetings.Overlappings().Any();
    overlappingMeetings.Dump();
    meetingsOverlap.Dump();
}

public static class StaffMeetings
{
    public static IEnumerable<Meeting[]> Overlappings(this IEnumerable<Meeting> meetings)
    {
        var first = (Meeting)null;
        foreach (var meeting in meetings.OrderBy(m => m.Start))
        {
            if (first != null && meeting.OverlapsWith(first))
            {
                yield return new [] { first, meeting };
            }
            first = meeting;
        }
    }
}
public class Meeting
{
    public DateTime Start { get; private set; }
    public DateTime End { get; private set; }

    public Meeting(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        if (end < start)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot create a meeting that ends before it starts.");
        }
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }
    
    public bool OverlapsWith(Meeting first) 
    {
        return first.End > this.Start;
    }
}
```

---

## Better Code

I decided to go a little bit further and see if I could make it so that if you had multiple meetings that started at the same time or multiple meetings during the time of one meeting that it would still show all the overlapping meetings.

I ran into an issue where it would check the meeting against itself so I changed the way I compared the meetings in the `Overlappings` extension method.  So here is what I did:

- I moved the queries to their own variables to make it easier to work with.
- I also created a new `List<Meeting>` so that I had a way of marking off all the meetings that I had already checked so that I was not checking two meetings in reverse order.
- I created a LINQ query to get all the unchecked meetings and I named it appropriately

Here is what the `Overlappings` method looks like now.

```
public static IEnumerable<Meeting[]> Overlappings(this IEnumerable<Meeting> meetings)
{
    var first = (Meeting)null;
    var orderedMeetings = meetings.OrderBy(m => m.Start);
    var checkedMeetings = new List<Meeting>();
    
    foreach (var meeting in orderedMeetings)
    {
        if (first != null)
        {
            checkedMeetings.Add(first);
            var uncheckedMeetings = orderedMeetings.Where(x => (x.Start >= first.Start && !(x == first)) && !checkedMeetings.Any(m => m == x));
            
            foreach (var meet in uncheckedMeetings)
            {
                if (first.OverlapsWith(meet))
                {
                    yield return new[] { first, meet };
                }
            }
        }
        first = meeting;
    }
}
```

this allows me to run this set of Meetings

```
    Meeting[] meetings = new Meeting[]
    {
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 21:30", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:00", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:10", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:30", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 20:00", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 21:30", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 22:10", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 22:20", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:20", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:50", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:20", format), DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 00:00", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 09:00", format), DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 12:00", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 09:00", format), DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 10:00", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 11:00", format), DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 11:30", format))
    };
```

and get these results

[image: Overlapping Meetings Results from LINQPad 5]

Comment: Posted a ***Rags-to-riches*** question for follow up to this answer --> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/144790/18427