# Too Many Staff Meetings

Tags: c#, linq, rags-to-riches

[I recently got in really deep on a question to find the overlapping meetings](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144567/verify-if-meeting-datetime-ranges-overlap-in-an-ienumerable-list-of-meetings) and I rewrote a bit of the code and added some things to the code, and I would just like a general review of my code and what I could do to make it even better, maybe performance wise or whatever.

Here is my LINQPad 5 Code Dump, you should be able to copy paste into LINQPad and run it, I don't think I did anything that is too cutting edge.

```
{
    var format = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat;
    Meeting[] meetings = new Meeting[]
    {
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 21:30", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:00", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:10", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:30", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 20:00", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 21:30", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 22:10", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 22:20", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:20", format), DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:50", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015 23:20", format), DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 00:00", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 09:00", format), DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 12:00", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 09:00", format), DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 10:00", format)),
        new Meeting(DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 11:00", format), DateTime.Parse("1/2/2015 11:30", format))
    };

    var overlappingMeetings = meetings.Overlappings();
    var meetingsOverlap = meetings.Overlappings().Any();
    overlappingMeetings.Dump();
    meetingsOverlap.Dump();
}

public static class StaffMeetings
{
    public static IEnumerable<Meeting[]> Overlappings(this IEnumerable<Meeting> meetings)
    {
        var first = (Meeting)null;
        var orderedMeetings = meetings.OrderBy(m => m.Start);
        var checkedMeetings = new List<Meeting>();

        foreach (var meeting in orderedMeetings)
        {
            if (first != null)
            {
                checkedMeetings.Add(first);
                var uncheckedMeetings = orderedMeetings.Where(x => (x.Start >= first.Start && !(x == first)) && !checkedMeetings.Any(m => m == x));
                foreach (var meet in uncheckedMeetings)
                {
                    if (first.OverlapsWith(meet))
                    {
                        yield return new[] { first, meet };
                    }
                }
            }
            first = meeting;
        }
    }
}
public class Meeting
{
    public DateTime Start { get; private set; }
    public DateTime End { get; private set; }

    public Meeting(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        if (end < start)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot create a meeting that ends before it starts.");
        }
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }

    public bool OverlapsWith(Meeting second)
    {
        return this.End > second.Start;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

here are the results of that run as well

[image: Overlapping meeting results]

Did I miss anything?

Are there more edge cases that I didn't consider?

Is there a nice, neat, acceptable way of streamlining the foreach statements with the if statements inside of them?  (*Kind of curious if it is possible to one line it*)

Comment: Performance-wise, I think you can find overlapping meetings in \$O(N)\$ and not \$O(n^2)\$. About Linq, make sure you understand how it works. From what i remember it doesn't perform the query until it have to, so this can be \$n^2\$ instead of \$2n\$ when performing a query on query.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should edit your question or not but didn't you forget to copy the `void Main()`? It's not a copy&paste yet ;-)

Comment: in LINQPad 5 I didn't need it to run the code...lol

Comment: wow, I didn't know you could define classes in the _Statement(s)_ mode - this explains the missing `Main`.

Comment: @limonana, what do you mean?

Comment: Could you post the original test data? The screenshot shows _9:30_ which is not in your test code.

Comment: @t3chb0t, 9:30 PM == 21:00  I don't know why the original test data had meetings at night, but I kept them anyway.

Comment: the contract for `overlapsWith` is not respected. Because of its wording, such a method would be expected to be symmetrical.

Comment: @limonana is Runtime Complexity not related to the LINQ Queries?  I am not going through the entire set of data in the second loop, so the runtime complexity should be something like **O(NLogN)** instead of N squared. is that not correct?

Comment: @njzk2, I coded for the requirements, by ordering the meetings before comparing them, I don't need to check the other condition because of the way that I wrote the `Overlappings` method.  if you are suggesting that the code would be simpler if we tested both conditions and changed that method, please post a review as to what you would do differently and why.

Comment: @Malachi I think the method name should reflect this detail of the implementation: you can only pass a meeting that starts later in this method.

Comment: @njzk2 that would be a good thing to mention in a review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had given it a second thought and I came up with another solution. For the sake of simplicity I replaced the `DateTime` with `int`.

Particularly I did the following:

- each meeting has two points that can be identified as start or end point
- each point has a parent (its meeting)

These `o--o` are example meetings that I used for testing. `\` and `/` indicate an overlap.

```
  o-o    o------o      o----o    o--o
     |    \      |    |    /    |
      o----o      o--o     o---o
                     |     \
                     o------o

          2                3
```

The algorithm works like this:

- I don't sort the meetings but add all points to a collection first
- now I sort the points
- I loop over each point and if it's a start point then I add it to the hashset, consecutive start points indicate an overlap; if it's an end point then I *dump* the hashset if it contains more then one point as a result and clear it

Source:

```
{
    Meeting[] meetings = new Meeting[]
    {
            new Meeting(4, 6),
            new Meeting(8, 13),
            new Meeting(11, 18),
            new Meeting(20, 23),
            new Meeting(23, 30),
            new Meeting(25, 30),
            new Meeting(29, 33),
            new Meeting(35, 37),
    };

    var overlappingMeetings = meetings.Overlappings();
    var meetingsOverlap = meetings.Overlappings().Any();
    overlappingMeetings.Select(m => m.Select(y => y.ToString())).Dump();
    meetingsOverlap.Dump();
}

public static class StaffMeetings
{
    public static IEnumerable<Meeting[]> Overlappings(this IEnumerable<Meeting> meetings)
    {
        var meetingSet = new HashSet<Meeting>();
        var points = meetings.Select(x => new[] { x.Start, x.End }).SelectMany(x => x).OrderBy(x => x.Value);
        foreach (var point in points)
        {
            switch (point.Type)
            {
                case PointType.Start:
                    meetingSet.Add(point.Parent);
                    break;
                case PointType.End:
                    if (meetingSet.Count > 1)
                    {
                        yield return meetingSet.ToArray();
                    }
                    meetingSet.Clear();
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}

public enum PointType
{
    Start,
    End
}

public class Point
{
    public Point(int value, PointType type, Meeting parent)
    {
        Value = value;
        Type = type;
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public Meeting Parent { get; }
    public int Value { get; }
    public PointType Type { get; }
}

public class Meeting
{
    public Point Start { get; private set; }
    public Point End { get; private set; }

    public Meeting(int start, int end)
    {
        Start = new Point(start, PointType.Start, this);
        End = new Point(end, PointType.End, this);
    }

    public bool OverlapsWith(Meeting second)
    {
        return this.End.Value > second.Start.Value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"({Start.Value}, {End.Value})";
    }
}
```

[image: Meetings result]

The modified loop returns the same results as the original code:

```
    foreach (var point in points)
    {
        switch (point.Type)
        {
            case PointType.Start:
                meetingSet.Add(point.Parent);
                break;
            case PointType.End:
                meetingSet.Remove(point.Parent);
                break;
        }
        if (meetingSet.Count == 2)
        {
            yield return meetingSet.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am kind of curious if you could do the same thing with DateTime variables? ...

Comment: @Malachi sure, you just use the [`DateTime.Ticks Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that: _Gets the number of ticks that represent the date and time of this instance._ There is also a special construtor that you can pass ticks.

Comment: Be sure to implement a good `Equals` and `HashCode`, `HashSet` makes use of those.

Answer (score 8):

#### Just a quick shot

This

> ```
> public override bool Equals(object obj)
> {
>     return base.Equals(obj);
> }
> public override int GetHashCode()
> {
>     return base.GetHashCode();
> }
> ```

doesn't buy you anything. Overriding a method and the calling the `base` method is just rubbish which lays around in the codebase.

Comment: Sorry, need to run to get my train. Maybe I will add more tomorrow.

Comment: I was thinking this didn't really do anything, I was going to add a Title and a Guid for an ID, but the ID didn't feel right... good answer, thank you

Comment: [Call base inside override](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/305120/38663)

Answer (score 4):

If you want equality/hashing in a meaningful fashion (not sure if that's a real requirement), here's some boilerplate:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var second = obj as Meeting;

    return (second != null)
        && ((second.Start == this.Start)
        && (second.End == this.End));
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        var hash = 17;

        hash = 23 * hash + this.Start.GetHashCode();
        return 31 * hash + this.End.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: these methods were left over from my thoughts of having more than one meeting with the same start and end times. I should have taken them out because I didn't give a way to specify the title which is something else I was thinking about in one of my versions with the overridden methods.  in this case your equality wouldn't work for what I was going to do.  other than that I like the methods and recognize the `GetHashCode()` method

Answer (score 3):

I think you can find overlapping meetings in \$O(N)\$. Have you tried?

About LINQ:

Of course it affects the runtime complexity. If you assume that query is \$O(N)\$ but it takes \$O(N^2)\$ then the runtime complexity is different.

**This is my analysis:**

- `var orderedMeetings = meetings.OrderBy(m => m.Start);` is \$O(N)\$
- `foreach (var meeting in orderedMeetings)` is \$O(N)\$
- `var uncheckedMeetings = orderedMeetings.Where(....);` is \$O(N)\$ or \${O(N^2)}\$

This is the part I am not sure of.  This is a query done on query (`orderedMeetings` is a query). From what I remember it doesn't perform the query until it has to, so this can cause \$n^2\$ instead of \$2n\$ when performing a query on query. When you understand this you will understand the runtime complexity.

Comment: I think that my next attempt will look something like @t3chb0t's answer, I like his idea, have you taken a look at [his answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/144820/18427)?

Comment: Also did you see my ["selfie" answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/144811/18427)?  I am not sure if this makes the complexity any better though.  it might be slightly better, if any.

Comment: sorting a sequence of items is O(n*log(n)), not O(n).  Additionally, the OP's code re-orders and re-searches through the code for each item in the sequence, so the end result is O((n^2)*log(n)).

Answer (score 1):

Not getting then need for

```
!checkedMeetings.Any(m => m == x)
```

You have already checked for

```
!(x == first)
```

If you order by Start and then End desc you can stop looking once you find the first non overlap

```
if (first.OverlapsWith(meet))
{
     yield return new[] { first, meet };
}
else  
{
     break;
}
```

Comment: the `!(x==first)` makes sure we aren't checking the meeting against itself, but would still allow checking the meeting against already checked meetings.  the whole point was to check if there were multiple meetings that overlapped a single meeting, and a meeting that overlapped one meeting but not another that overlapped it.  please see the example meetings that I used to test my code.

Comment: Not getting how an already checked meeting could be in there.  You just added first and have a condition (x.Start >= first.Start && !(x == first)) and  orderedMeetings is ordered

Comment: if I remove `!checkedMeetings.Any(m => m == x)` then I get 2 extra meeting overlaps that are repeats of other checks. it doesn't work.  punch the code into LinqPad or whatever and run the code.

Comment: that query says `grab the meetings that start at the same time as this meeting or any meeting in the future and do not grab this current meeting and do not grab meetings that we already checked` I can see where you are confused now.  I put 2 meetings in there that start at the same time, if there are multiple meetings that start at the same time it keeps the algorithm from checking the 2 meetings against each other in reverse.

Comment: It is an expensive check.

Comment: I haven't seen an alternative yet. if it is not done the results are not correct.

Comment: you have shown me that some of those conditions are not needed, I will post an answer and explain

Comment: see my selfie review and tell me what you think, I am curious.

Answer (score 1):

Because the meetings are ordered and there is a list of already checked meetings, all that is needed is that the already checked meetings are not included when checking more meetings.

this makes the inside query a lot cleaner.

```
var uncheckedMeetings = orderedMeetings.Where(x => !checkedMeetings.Any(m => m == x));
```

These pieces of that Query were Redundant

```
x.Start >= first.Start
```

And

```
!(x == first)
```

so getting rid of them didn't make a difference, it just makes the code cleaner and might make the query a little more efficient.